# Swift Dictionary Memory Consumption is Astronomical

Tags: xcode, swift, dictionary, memory, trie

Can anyone help shed some light on why the below code consumes well over 100 MB of RAM during runtime?

```
public struct Trie<Element : Hashable> {
    private var children: [Element:Trie<Element>]
    private var endHere : Bool

    public init() {
        children = [:]
        endHere  = false
    }
    public init<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(_ seq: S) {
        self.init(gen: seq.generate())
    }
    private init<G : GeneratorType where G.Element == Element>(var gen: G) {
        if let head = gen.next() {
            (children, endHere) = ([head:Trie(gen:gen)], false)
        } else {
            (children, endHere) = ([:], true)
        }
    }
    private mutating func insert<G : GeneratorType where G.Element == Element>(var gen: G) {
        if let head = gen.next() {
            let _ = children[head]?.insert(gen) ?? { children[head] = Trie(gen: gen) }()
        } else {
            endHere = true
        }
    }
    public mutating func insert<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(seq: S) {
        insert(seq.generate())
    }
}

var trie = Trie<UInt32>()
for i in 0..<300000 {
    trie.insert([UInt32(i), UInt32(i+1), UInt32(i+2)])
}
```

Based on my calculations total memory consumption for the above data structure should be somewhere around the following...

```
3 * count * sizeof(Trie<UInt32>)
```

Or –

```
3 * 300,000 * 9 = 8,100,000 bytes = ~8 MB
```

How is it that this data structure consumes well over 100 MB during runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof` reports only the static footprint on the stack, which the `Dictionary` is just kind of a wrapper of the reference to its internal reference type implementation, and also the copy on write support. In other words, the key-value pairs and the hash table of your dictionary are allocated on the heap, which is not covered by `sizeof`. This applies to all other Swift collection types.

In your case, you are creating three `Trie` - and indirectly three dictionaries - every iteration of the 300000. I wouldn't be surprised if the 96-byte allocations mentioned by @Macmade is the minimum overhead of a dictionary (e.g. its hash bucket).

There might also be cost related to growing storage. So you may try to see if setting a `minimumCapacity` on the dictionary would help. On the other hand, if you do not need a divergent path generated per iteration, you may consider an indirect enum as an alternative, e.g.

```
public enum Trie<Element> {
    indirect case Next(Element, Trie<Element>)
    case End
}
```

which should use less memory.

Comment: Anders, you are correct. I've been playing with the minimumCapacity and it seems to have no effect for values ranging from 0-2. The documentation also states that "The actual capacity will be the smallest power of 2 that's >= minimumCapacity".

Answer (score 1):

Size of your struct is **9** bytes, not 5.

You can check it with `sizeof`:

```
let size = sizeof( Trie< UInt32 > );
```

Also, you iterate 300'000 times, but insert 3 values (of course, it's a trie). So that's 900'000.
Anyway, that does not explain by itself the memory consumption you are observing.

I'm not really fluent in Swift, and I don't understand you code.
Maybe there's also some error in it, making it allocate more memory than needed.

But anyway, in order to understand what's happening, you need to run your code in **Instruments** (command-i).

On my machine, I can see 900'000 **96 bytes** allocations by `swift_slowAlloc`.
That's more like it...

Why 96 bytes, assuming there's no error in your code?
Well, it might be because of the way memory is allocated for your elements.
When satisfying a request, the memory allocator may allocate more memory than requested. That may be because it needs some internal metadata, because of paging, because of alignment, ...

But even though, it seems really exaggerated, so use instruments and double check what your code is doing.

Comment: Macmade, thanks for your response. You are correct, the struct size is 9 bytes. I updated my question after realizing this. You also correct that this still doesn't explain the ridiculous amount of memory being consumed here. I too used instruments and notices the 96 byte allocations totaling 82.4 MB. But why? More investigation required...

Comment: You're welcome. It might also be bug due to swift_slowalloc. Have you checked this radar? Looks like your example: http://www.openradar.me/21375421

Comment: Just read through the radar briefly – I will need to investigate this further and try to reproduce with a more simplified example in order to confirm.

Comment: It seems like this bug was fixed in Xcode 7 beta 5 so we can rule this out as a possible culprit.